# Creating SSL socket using imported certificate without private key

Tags: java, ssl, sslsocketfactory

Im very new to SSL and to be frank i've found implementation to be pretty confusing so sorry if my question seems clueless or off base.

So i have a SSL socket server using a self signed certificate in the form of a p12 file. I want to have a client socket be able to connect to this server WITHOUT having access to the private key. I do however want the client to be able to verify that the server is not an imposter and does have the private key.

my problem is that i cannot seem to create a SSLContext and thus a SSLSocketFactory using anything other than a p12 file. Ideally i would create my SSLSocketFactory using the certificate root file.

heres the way i have my client setup:

```
public class SSLClient {
    
    private static final String TLS_VERSION = "TLSv1.2";

    public static void run(int serverPort, String certName, char[] certPass) throws Exception {

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        InputStream certInputStream = TLSClient.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + certName);
        trustStore.load(certInputStream, certPass);
        certInputStream.close();
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        InputStream keyStoreInputStream = TLSClient.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + certName);
        keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, certPass);
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, certPass);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong());

        SocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        try (Socket connection = factory.createSocket("localhost", serverPort)) {
            ((SSLSocket) connection).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {TLS_VERSION});
            SSLParameters sslParams = new SSLParameters();
            sslParams.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS");
            ((SSLSocket) connection).setSSLParameters(sslParams);


            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(input.readLine());
            new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(),true).println("client reply");
        }
    }
}
```

Ive tried using the root certificate (.crt) and a PEM file but both of them give me an input stream error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.toDerInputStream(DerValue.java:1155)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2013)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473)
    at TLSClient.run(TLSClient.java:16)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

**My current approach/solution to this**: i created an "empty" p12 file for the client using the servers root certificate. This appears to be working as intended... is there a problem doing it this way?

made using:

openssl pkcs12 -export -in myCert.crt -out myCertPks.p12 -name alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to import the trusted CAs public certificate in a Java keystore (you manipulate them with `keytool`, a CLI tool that's delivered with Java).

If you use the file *cacerts* from a subfolder of your `JAVA_HOME`, it will be recognized by your JVM automatically.

You find documentation about `keytool` in the [tool docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/keytool.html) of JDK (linked it for Java 21, but version is probably not that relevant). Also a better description of the exact location of the *cacerts* file, it's default password etc. are documented there.

In this way you don't have to mess around with `KeyStore`, `TrustManager`, etc., just create the `SSLSocket` with a default `SSLSocketFactory` and you're good.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specifically use Java SSLContext, you can use a custom TrustManager that directly trusts the specified certificate.

```
public static TrustManager[] getTrustManagers(String certificateFilePath) throws Exception {
    // Load the certificate
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    TrustManager[] trustManagers;
    
    try (InputStream certificateInputStream = new FileInputStream(certificateFilePath)) {
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(certificateInputStream);

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts only the specified certificate
        trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                        // Allow any client certificates
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        // Check if the server certificate matches the specified certificate
                        if (!chain[0].equals(certificate)) {
                            throw new CertificateException("Server certificate not trusted");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new X509Certificate[0];
                    }
                }
        };
        return trustManagers;
    }
}
```

Then use the created TrustManager to create the SSLContext,

```
        String certificateFilePath = "path/to/your/certificate.crt";
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = getTrustManagers(certificateFilePath);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);
```